# Spark, read from Kafka stream failing AnalysisException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark 2.4.5, Kafka 2.3.1 on my local machine.

I am able to produce and consume messages on Kafka with bootstrap server config "`localhost:9092`”

While trying to setup reader with spark streaming API, I am getting an error as

> Exception Message: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o166.load. : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find
>   data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the
>   deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration
>   Guide".;

Spark Code I am trying to execute:

```
df1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
 .option("subscribe", "topic1")\
 .load()
```

How to check if Spark has data source "Kafka"? If not then how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` with `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5` option to pull the corresponding packages into classpath.  See [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying) that it mention in the exception.